# Abstract Classes - A glitch in my program

Tags: abstract-class

So I'm trying to write a program with 3 classes (not including the class with the method). These are a worker class, which should be abstract, which has a name, salaryrate, and a few miscellaneous methods like getname, getsalary, and computepay(int hours). And I have 2 other methods, one called hourlyworker and one called salariedworker which are subclasses of workers and are non abstract. hourlyworker's compute pay should return the hourly wage for the actual number of hours worked, if hours is at most 40. Above 40 the excess is paid at 1 1/2 of the regular rate
For salaried worker it is salaryrate * 40 hours, no matter how many hours. 
The problem is my salaried worker works fine, but for my hourlyworker somehow the hours variable is already defined as 40 or something....I'm not sure what is the problem. Could you inspect my program and see what's wrong? Thanks

```
 abstract class Worker {

String name;
double salaryRate;

public abstract double computePay(int hours);

public abstract String getName();

public abstract double getSalary();
 }

  class HourlyWorker extends Worker {

public HourlyWorker(String workerName, double workersalaryRate) {
    name = workerName;
    salaryRate = workersalaryRate;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public double getSalary() {
    return salaryRate;
}

@Override
public double computePay(int hours) {
    if (hours <= 40) {
        System.out.println(hours);
        System.out.println(salaryRate);
        System.out.println(salaryRate * hours);
        return salaryRate * hours;
    } else{
        System.out.println((salaryRate * 40) + (3 / 2) * (hours - 40) * salaryRate);
        return (salaryRate * 40) + (3 / 2) * (hours - 40) * salaryRate;
    }
}
 }

  class SalariedWorker extends Worker {

public SalariedWorker(String workerName, double workersalaryRate) {
    name = workerName;
    salaryRate = workersalaryRate;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public double getSalary() {
    return salaryRate;
}

@Override
public double computePay(int hours) {
    System.out.println(salaryRate * 40);
    return salaryRate * 40;
}
}

 public class WorkerTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Worker Bob = new HourlyWorker("Bob", 15);
    Worker JohnnyBoy = new SalariedWorker("Johnny", 20);

    Bob.computePay(20);
    JohnnyBoy.computePay(50);
}
```

}

This should give 300 and 800 + 3/2 * 10 * 20 = 1100 but it gives 300 and 800. What's wrong?

Comment: I found out what's wrong...I accidentally let Bob be hourlyworker so I switched it up.

Comment: But now I have a new problem....the computePay for Bob doesn't work...it thinks that it should do 50*salaryrate not 40*salaryrate + 10 * salaryrate*3/2

Comment: Nvm'd found the problem lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what's wrong...I accidentally let Bob be hourlyworker so I switched it up.

~Sorry about that.